# Cannot see SOME images on Stack site posts

Tags: google-chrome

I've asked a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1502216/images-from-imgur-not-showing-in-my-posts-on-superuser) before, but the solution turns out not to be valid.

Chrome, current version.

In some posts on the Stack Exchange network, the images show as broken icons and when I open the image in a new tab, I get this error.

> This site can’t be reached
>
> i.stack.imgur.com unexpectedly closed the
>   connection. Try:
>
> - Checking the connection
> - Checking the proxy and the firewall
> - Running Windows Network Diagnostics
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

When I open the same post in a different Chrome profile session, the image loads fine. It's just my main Chrome profile that has the problems in SOME posts only.

I'm not running any VPN. Clearing cookies doesn't help. Refresh doesn't help.

It does not make any sense that one Chrome session can access the image and at the same time another session can't.

Rebooting seems to help, but I can't reboot my machine that often.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Does restarting chrome in the same profile help?

Comment: Do the two profiles have the same addons? Have you tried disabling addons?

Comment: Yes it does. But what is the systemic issue?

Comment: Try clearing the chrome cache - could be chrome thinks the images are cached and they aren't ...

Comment: I can see images fine for most posts in my main profile. It's just that they sometimes error out. Not always. Doesn't that rule out extensions and add-ins as culprits? It's the inconsistency that gets me.

Comment: Anything can be a culprit if it has a (rarely triggered) bug in the code. The trick to fixing bugs is to find the repro cases so they can be debugged.

Comment: I've cleared the cache. Now I need to watch it for a while.

Comment: Example. Something in the Stack Overflows Extra (SOX) script triggers runaway processes in Firefox, but only after a long time running. Trying to narrow down exactly which of the scripts many options is causing it has so far eluded me and it's too time consuming to keep trying to find it and having to restart FF etc ... so I've no info to pass to the developer to get it fixed.

Comment: It may not be the cache of course. Just my first thought.

Comment: Did you check the Chrome Developer console for errors?

Comment: Is this Windows  by the way? What version?

Comment: See also all the answers to https://superuser.com/questions/390437/imgur-com-is-not-resolving-properly-dns-issue-on-home-network for other possible causes

Comment: Windows 10, 1903 (18362.476)